Determining transformer equivalent circuit components
I have made a PCB based planar transformer with a turns-ratio of 8:6. I am considering the T-model as shown below:

In the T-model, Lp is the primary side leakage inductance, Ls' is the secondary side leakage inductance referred to the primary and Lm is the magnetizing inductance. The following tests are conducted (the values are consistent for a frequency sweep from 100kHz to 1 MHz):

Connect the primary side to the impedance analyzer keeping the secondary open: (Lp + Lm) = 105.6 µH
Connect the primary side to the impedance analyzer keeping the secondary shorted: (Lp + (Lm || Ls')) = 1.26 µH
Connect the secondary side to the impedance analyzer keeping the primary open: (Ls' + Lm) = 60.76 µH
Connect the secondary side to the impedance analyzer keeping the secondary shorted: (Ls' + (Lm || Lp)) = 0.74 µH

I have solved these equations and have determined the component values as:

Lp = 26 µH
Ls' = -19 µH
Lm = 80 µH

Are these values correct? The secondary side leakage (transferred to the primary) is negative. The transformer self resonant frequency is in the MHz range. Are my values correct? If I am to design a series resonant converter utilizing this transformer, can I consider 26 µH as the resonant inductor along with an external capacitor?
If I am wrong in my calculations, how should I proceed correctly?

The reason for the close vote is: needs more detail or clarity. Please specify what more is required. I will be more than happy to add it to the question.

Made with Maple ...

It seems that there are 4 solutions.
The solution where Lm1 and Lm2 (and positive) are "near" should be cared.
It is the first in the sequence list where Lm1=79.6 uH and Lm2=79.9 uH.
Then Lp=26.4 uH and Ls= -19.1 uH ...
So, you are "right", but I don't understand why Ls is "negative" ... (not checked).
As it is a "theoretical" background, it is possible. Confirmed by microcap v12.


Thank you. Even if the secondary side leakage is negative, can I still use the primary side leakage as it is to build a series resonant circuit utilizing an external capacitor?

Yes. You can use it. I have done this in microcap v12.

When you used the values from connecting the impedance analyzer to the secondary, did you account for the turns ratio?
You should be using Ls, Lp', and Lm' for those two values, where Lp' and Lm' are referred from Lp and Lm to the secondary. That would apply a factor of (6/8)^2 to Lp, Lm, and Ls'
I'm not at my computer to calculate exactly, but that would seem to line up with your values.
On the primary side:
Lp is around 0.7 uH
Ls' ~ 0.7 uH
Lm ~ 100 uH
On the secondary side:
Lp' is around (6/8)^2 * 0.7 uH = ~0.4 uH
Ls ~ 0.4 uH
Lm' ~ 60 uH


Are these values correct?

Yes and no. The values are correct for a particular model of a transformer, but the labels or meanings you have assigned to the components in that model are incorrect.
The transformer you describe consists of two coupled inductors that have self inductances of 105.6 uH and 60.76 uH. The self inductance of each coil is what you measure when you measure the inductance of that coil with the other coil open-circuit.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
We don't know the value of \$k\$ yet, but we will find it soon.
This model of coupled inductors is equivalent to a "T" model of inductors.

simulate this circuit
In this model M is the Mutual Inductance. It is NOT the what is called the magnetizing inductance. Further, the inductors I have labeled L1-M and L2-M are NOT "leakage inductances. In your model, you have Lp and Ls' which you describe as "leakage inductances". Your numbers are right, but those numbers do not refer to what is called "leakage inductance", but to inductances within this T model.
We can calculate the value of M using the measurements you took for the inductance seen on the primary with the secondary shorted, and for the inductance seen on the secondary with the primary shorted.
The inductance seen on the primary, with the secondary shorted is
\$(L_1 - M) + ( M \;||\; (L_2 - M)\;) = L_1 - \frac{M^2}{L_2}\$
Plugging in your measured values, we get \$M = \$ 79.6222 uH.
Similarly, the inductance seen on the secondary, with the primary shorted is
\$(L_2 - M) + (M\;||\;(L_1 - M)\;) = L_2 - \frac{M^2}{L_1}\$
which, using your measured values, gives \$M = \$ 79.61222 uH.
The calculations are close, but not exact. We will choose 79.617 uH as the value of M.
This makes our model

simulate this circuit
These numbers match your calculations, and this is a perfectly good model of your transformer. It just doesn't match your language regarding "leakage inductance".
Regarding the negative value of one of the inductances, this is typical of this model. It yields negative inductances. There is no need to be troubled by this negative value. It works fine in all the formulae you are likely to come across. Just remember that it is a negative value inductance, and enter it as such, and remember that it is not a leakage inductance.
Having found M, we can now find k in the original coupled inductor model.
$$k = \frac{M}{\sqrt{L_1L_2}} = 0.994$$
This is a very good coupling ratio, by the way.
Next we turn to leakage inductance.
Notice that in our derivation of the T model, we did not use the turns ratio. We only needed three parameters, L1, L2 and M. There are common (lossless) transformer models that require 4 parameters, and one of those parameters is, in a way, redundant. With the three parameters L1, L2, and M, we don't need to know the turns ratio. However, it turns out that we can't calculate leakage inductance in one of those models without assigning a turns ratio.
So, is there a problem? Actually, yes. You describe the turns ratio as 8:6, and physically, that may be true. However, if we calculate
$$\alpha = \sqrt\frac{L_1}{L_2}$$
we get \$\alpha = 1.318\$ which is near 8/6 = 1.333, but is different enough for us question the propriety of using 8/6 in our model. You can use either number, or even some completely made up number in the model, and this will affect how much leakage occurs on either side of the ideal transformer in our model, and will also affect any concept of the "total" leakage inductance. But all of the models will have the same circuit behavior. However, if we deviate too far from \$\alpha\$, one of the leakage inductances that is derived will become negative. That will be the case if we choose 1.333 as the value of n. So, we will continue the example using 1.318 instead of 1.333.
The model we will use is the following. There are many equivalent models, and I will not explain here how to transform from one to another.

simulate this circuit
In this model, the transformer is ideal, L_m is called the magnetizing inductance, L_k1 is the primary side leakage inductance, and L_k2 is the secondary side leakage inductance. "n" is the "turns ratio", which we will choose to have a value of 1.318, but which we could have chosen to be 1.333 or some other value.
The formulae we use to convert our previous model to the current model are these.
$$L_m = nM$$
$$L_{k1} = L_1-nM$$
$$L_{k2} = L_2-\frac{M}{n}$$
using the values found previously, we get
\$L_m =104.935\$ uH.
\$L_{k1} = 0.7\$ uH.
\$L_{k2} = 0.35\$ uH.

simulate this circuit
Now, just to do a quick sanity check to see that my numbers could possibly be accurate, will do a simulation of the two models.

simulate this circuit

At least in this case, the two outputs match exactly, so I'm somewhat confident I didn't make any mistakes in my calculations.
